# Installing Geant4 alongside GEANT3: Question for Physics StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, scope, software-questions

I intend to ask the following question:

**Can I install [Geant4](http://www.geant4.org/geant4/) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geant4)) alongside GEANT-3 ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEANT-3)) on my Ubuntu 15.04? I have already installed GEANT3. How can I install Geant4 without making any problems?**

Can I ask the question on Physics StackExchange?
May be we should introduce a tag or site for computing packages and resources for physics.

I have already asked similar question on StackOverflow Meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298562/3623705).

Comment: It's probably more appropriate for the [Computational Science Stack Exchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). We generally discourage questions about software on the grounds they're not directly about physics. You could try asking in the Physics chat. Is there no support community for the software?

Comment: I would agree with the Meta SO answer that SU/AU/UL are probably better options (since it is about installing the software and not using it)

Comment: On the other hand, Physics is more likely than Comp Sci to contain somebody who has actually installed and used Geant - it isn't exactly common software that everyone uses (unless you are interested in rad transport).

Comment: The answer to your question is that they share almost nothing and you can probably just go ahead.

Comment: How do you know that they share nothing? I mean I do not question your knowledge but I also want to understand how you really know this.

Comment: Because Geant4 is a major re-write in a new language. Geant3 was a fortran 77 framework (which paired well with CERNLIB) and Geant4 is c++ framework (and pairs reasonably well with ROOT and with a few other modern analysis frameworks). There may still be a small about of fortran code still hanging around in odd corners of Geant4, but there isn't much.